# Google slide, Invalid requests[0].replaceAllShapesWithImage: The operation is not allowed on notes page element g19e33b833f_2_9

Tags: google-slides-api

I create a shape on Gslide within text {{company_logo}}, but when I execute the request i get this message :
Invalid requests[0].replaceAllShapesWithImage: The operation is not allowed on notes page element

```
{
  "requests": 
  [
    {
      "replaceAllShapesWithImage": 
      {
        "imageUrl": "https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratuites/logo-de-pomme_318-40184.jpg",
        "containsText": 
        {
          "text": "{{company_logo}}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I make also make test on the url https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate and i get the same error message
By the way this request was working noramly and i create slides automatically, until today

Comment: Miraculously, It's working now.
After i wrote 2 issues and emailed  Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Slides API team member here -- This was a bug on our side that was fixed on 12/20. Apologies for the breakage.

Link to this issue on our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4991